# Security Patch (SUPEE-6285) – Install Immediately In Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-6285

How To Resolve New Magento Security Patch (SUPEE-6285) – Install Immediately In Magento 1.9.0.1 please find the below image

[image]

I have tried this code

```
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh");
```

But still it is showing same error. How to rectify this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUPEE-6285\_CE\_1.9.0.0 - 1.9.1.1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134990/supee-6285-ce-1-9-0-0-1-9-1-1)

Comment: **Not a duplicate!** the linked question asks for Magento version compatibility. This one asks about the message in the backend. Completely different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an error.

This is just a notification. You can go to the Messages inbox and "Mark as Read" .

To check if the patch is successfully installed, go to the `app/etc/` directory

When patches are applied a file named `applied.patches.list` is added in the `app/etc/` directory.

Next to that the patch is nothing more than a diff file so you can see what it should change when you open it and check in the targeted file if it is indeed changed.

You can test successful installation of the patches at https://shoplift.byte.nl

Comment: I have one more doubt.

Comment: what is that...??

Comment: In cache management i have enabled cache. but it is showing disable.

Answer (score 2):

The error you see is not an error. It is a notification and Magento won't recognize if this patch has been installed. You can install it correctly and it will still show up. You can mark it as read or delete it by going to your messages inbox.

Still these patches are rather important. You can check whether it was installed. In app/etc/applied.patches.list are the patches listed which are installed through a bash script. There are also modules which you can use but they do practically the same. I suggest keeping your live shop as clean as possible.

I also suggest updating to magento 1.9.2 which has all the latest patches included. You should be careful with this and test it in a development environment first. If you doubt your knowledge i suggest you consult a professional. Updates and patches may fail and or break your shop and no one wants that.

**Note on the answer above!**

shoplift.byte.nl only tests for the shoplift bug which was patched with SUPEE-5344. It won't test if your patch - SUPEE-6285 - was correctly installed. I hate not being able to comment...

Answer (score 2):

These notifications come from this RSS feed: http://notifications.magentocommerce.com/community/notifications.rss

There is no additional logic behind them, so this message won't disappear after you applied the patch, only when you go to `System > Notifications` and mark it as read.

If you saw the message "Patch has been applied successfully" after running the patch script, everything is fine. Or you can look at `app/etc/applied.patches.list` as suggested and search for `SUPEE-6285`. If it's there, the patch has been applied.

#### Example content of `applied.patches.list`:

```
-e 2015-07-09 13:01:37 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 | 7226d88b1eeb07a5fbc4e62be189a5219457cc14 | Mon Jun 22 16:32:26 2015 +0300 | 202596e441..7226d88b1e
patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php
```