# SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.0.0 - 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

What is the mean of this security patch.
SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.0.0 - 1.9.1.1

Is it compatible from version 1.9.0.0 to 1.9.1.1
or
Is it compatible with only 1.9.0.0 - 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is compatible for every Community version of Magento between 1.9.0.0 and 1.9.1.1 inclusive.

NB: After 1.9.1.1 the patch was shipped with Magento code.