# Magento 2.3.4 upgarde returns some security updates and features notification

Tags: patches, magento2.3.4

I'm working on Magento2.3.3. So I have planned to upgrade the Magento version from 2.3.3 to 2.3.4.

After the successful upgrade, the magento version was changed to 2.3.4.

But I got some notification related to security updates and features. Please refer to the below image.

[image]

Refer to the below image which shows in the admin notification message.

[image]

While referring to some suggestions, they reported about the applied.patches.list ( [reference link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74608/security-patch-supee-6285-install-immediately-in-magento-1-9-0-1) )

I'm not seeing any applied.patches.list in my app/etc/ folder.

How can able to get whether all the patches are applied successfully or not.

I can't able to check the successful patch installation using https://shoplift.byte.nl. Because of the upgraded code on my local.

Any solution here.

Answer (score 3):

Method 1: Disable Admin Notice Message in the backend

Step 1: Using your admin account to log in to Magento 2.

Step 2: In the left sidebar, you will see the Store section. Click on it and then go to Settings > Configuration.

Step 3: When you have finished the above step, you will see a section called Advanced in the panel on the left side. Expand it and choose Advanced which is under that section.

Step 4: Under the Disable Modules Output, you will see Magento_AdminNotification extension which is installed on your store.

Step 5: Choose Disable.

Step 6: Then, click on the Save Config button.

Step 7: Finally, clear the cache.

Comment: For your reference, However, from Magento 2.2.0, the section which allows you to disable module output will be removed from Admin.

Comment: Hello Ramya, I am telling that just its not for removal because if anyone want this option to upgrade to new version but we have to put it as optional if anyone can just don't want that section then just he or she can remove that block from xml.

Comment: But my doubt is, after the successful upgrade why it shows security updates and features.

Comment: Please dont disable the AdminNotification module, this is used for a lot more than just the new update notifications. And you can miss import notices on the health of your store by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the update is applied:
- In the admin panel in the bottom right of the page it will tell you your Magento version (should be `2.3.4` for latest version)
- Or you can run `php bin/magento --version` from the Magento root

The message that pops up on login is old (28th of Jan) and usually will say until you mark is as read / remove it. You can do this by login into the backend and going into "System > Other Settings > Notifications". And find the notification about the update and mark it as read / remove it.

### EDIT

The relevent module that controls these updates notifications is `Magento_ReleaseNotification`. If you really want to disable these messages in the future then disable this module rather than `Magento_AdminNotification`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Magento version as 2.3.4 in the admin panel. So, from your answer itself, if we are not changed the status of the message as read/remove, the notification will always show even we successfully complete the up-gradation process.

Comment: Correct, if you want to look into how it works more heres the module that controls it https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/ReleaseNotification